# Reading a TSV file to a web displayable datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wanted to read a TSV file that contains no headers but 7 integer types of data.

```
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10  
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10  
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10  
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10  
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10
```

I want to merge 4 elements to create two. For example, the first row:

```
37.791871   -122.396742 37.784070   -122.412320 12  14  10
```

to

```
37.791871,-122.396742   37.784070,-122.412320   12  14  10
```

I want to make a hashmap type data structure.

Like `map[rowNumber][element]` which get a value, in this case

```
map[0][1] = 37.784070,-122.412320
map[3][4] = 10
```

How would I programmatically create this? I can only deal with TSV files.

Comment: We are not here to design your system for you, or write the code for you. That's your job. We just (maybe) help fix what you've built.

Comment: I asked about a programatic approach to this, assisting in design logic fits the purpose of stackoverflow, please don't comment unless you are apart of the solution.